# Ruby/Jekyll Plugin - How to render liquid variables inside plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I'm creating a Jekyll plugin that executes an shell script with some (liquid or not) arguments.

I am having problems with it extrating the value of some liquid variables.
For example, if I use this plugin this way:

```
{% shellcmd image-responsive "{{ include.asset }}" %}
```

it is not rendering the `{{ include.asset }}` part. I need help, especially with this part.

The plugin, so far, is like this:

```
module Jekyll
  class ShellCommand < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
    end

    def render_variable(context)
      Liquid::Template.parse(@text).render(context)
    end

    def render(context)
      text = render_variable(@text)
      `#{text}`.strip
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('shellcmd', Jekyll::ShellCommand)
```

How it should be?

Comment: I'm looking up for the same answer. Have you figured out how to work around it?

Comment: I am not interested in contribuing to Jekyll at the moment. I have not tried the answer below of Stefan

Comment: Strange comment @alexandre1985. You first ask and than You are not interested? Perhaps I misinterpret Your comment.

Comment: @Stefan If this clarifies, I have moved on from making plugins to Jekyll and the Ruby language. Not that I need to justify, but some people think attribution of judgment to person suits well on a StackOverFlow.com technical answer

Answer (score 1):

Did not check this in code and just started play around with Jekyll so perhaps I'm wrong. But try `{% shellcmd image-responsive include.asset %}` (your line without curly braces).